# RPi.GPIO Not Found in Python 3

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, gpio, python-3.9

I am trying to get the GPIO module working on a Raspberry Pi 3B+. I have installed the libraries as below. It works fine in Python2 but not Python 3 (version 3.9).  Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
pi@raspberrypi:/usr/bin $ sudo apt-get install python-rpi.gpio python3-rpi.gpio
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-rpi.gpio is already the newest version (0.6.5~stretch-1).
python3-rpi.gpio is already the newest version (0.6.5~stretch-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
pi@raspberrypi:/usr/bin $ python2
Python 2.7.13 (default, Aug 22 2020, 10:03:02) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import RPi.GPIO
>>> 
pi@raspberrypi:/usr/bin $ python3
Python 3.9.0 (default, Jan 27 2021, 16:17:29) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import RPi.GPIO
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'RPi'
>>>
```

Comment: Why do you need that custom library? Kernel has officially supported one `libgpiod`.

Comment: I am a Raspberry Pi noob, so am just using the library recommended in the CanaKit package and the FreeNove accessories kit I received. Both use RPi.GPIO. I did not even bother to check for others.

Just tried to install libgpiod for python3 and it is not available. 

I tried a cache search and python3-libgpiod is not there. libgpiod-dev and gpiod are. I installed gpiod and got that working from shell, but unable to use it in Python without the wrapper.

Comment: Ah, i see now from where it comes! I have no idea what the distribution you are using (is it pure Debian? Or is it raspbian? According to https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=python3-libgpiod it probably never were in Debian stretch, I see though it in buster for Raspberry Pi), but Python bindings is a part of the library. Anyway, good luck with either (just note tha `RPi.GPIO` is only for RPi, while `libgpiod` code is portable).

Comment: I am using raspbian. Perhaps I should explain the background of why I am doing this... I am a Professor of Computer Science and we have undergone a program revision where we now have a course on the IoT. The ministry requirements (in Quebec the education ministry issues competencies we must address) indicate that this must include "connected devices" so we were planning on using Pi to collect data or some sort (which would then be put into Mongo and analyzed, hopefully with a little ML thrown in).

Comment: We are a Microsoft shop and software oriented so dealing with hardware and Linux will be a stretch for them (we do have some Linux in the program, but not a lot). Therefore, my desire to simplify that aspect and make it as easy as possible for them. I do not need portability and thought to go with the simplest solution to get them working. I will look more into the disto or raspbian and see if there is a libgpiod port.

Comment: Oh, nice. The “problem” with Linux or other OSS (open source software) is that the paradigm of portability is one of the basics concepts. So if you want that your students will be slightly more educated the better to tell and show them alternatives. JFYI: .Net IoT project https://github.com/dotnet/iot also supports `libgpiod` on Linux. Maybe you can consider using .Net Core?

Comment: While I appreciate the suggestions about the program we have spent many hours and much sweat on the content and the pedagogy.  Portability is not the focus of this course, nor, actually, is the Pi. I have gotten it working by installing buster. I am not sure if it was a path issue or a version issue but now the proper libraries are being found.

Thank you for all your help and suggestions.

Comment: I’m glad to hear that the problem solved. You may post your own answer, btw.